Matter development - Matter Accessory - Apple Ecosystem
What is the best way of logging the pairing / commissioning process of Matter and HomeKit Accessories (Console logs are encrypted / lacking).
I could not find any specific software or documentation provided by Apple regarding this (nor any other participant of the CSA).
